# Can't use variable from input box in other subs in same module

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

So I am trying to get a variable from an input box. I then use the variable to name my sheet. But I cannot reference the sheet in other subs in order to switch back to it. It gives me an error. My code is probably sloppy because I am new and I separate my subs probably more than I need to but I have been testing them a piece at a time. Anyway here it is:

```
Dim name As String
name = InputBox("Please enter the date of the report. Ex: 7-28 to 8-25-17. This will show up as: All HCM changes 7-28 to 8-25-17 for the tab name.", "Tab Name Date")
If Len(name) = 0 Then 'Checking if Length of name is 0 characters
    MsgBox "Valid date not entered. Please Re-Run the Macro to input the date.", vbCritical
Else
    MsgBox "The tab will now be named, All HCM changes " & name & "."
End If

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").name = ("All HCM changes " & name)

Call Change_Header_Colors
Call Insert_Columns
Call Create_LEGEND
Call Sort_by_Action_then_Last_Name
Call Freeze_Panes
```

In those calls, I am referencing the name variable. But it is giving me an error. I tried declaring the variable before the first sub in the module but that didn't work. This is how I am trying to use it in those calls.

```
Sub Sort_by_Action_then_Last_Name()
'
' This is ACTUALLY sorting by action then by person #. Which is what we 
wanted. Can change it easily.
'

'
Dim name As String

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All HCM changes " & name).Select
Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All HCM changes " & name).SORT.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All HCM changes " & name).SORT.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("A2:A246"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All HCM changes " & name).SORT.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("E2:E246"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All HCM changes " & name).SORT
    .SetRange Range("A1:U246")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Apart from Scott's solution, the way your code is setup, if the user doesn't provide a `name`, your code will continue after an 'invalid date entered' msgbox. You should either end the code at that stage or have the inputbox and its validation in some sort of `LOOP`

Comment: AH yes thanks! I was meaning to do that but got distracted! I need to put the input box into a LOOP so they have to input something. The rest of the code will still run correctly it looks like, but it just won't have the date on the tab. If I run the macro again, it won't run right anyway because it looks for Sheet1 but it is already changed to another name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variable to the other subs:

```
Sub Sort_by_Action_then_Last_Name(name as String)
```

and Remove the `Dim name as String` line from the secondary sub as you are declaring the variable in the call.

Then when you call it you would call it like:

```
Call Sort_by_Action_then_Last_Name(name)
```

Comment: AWESOME! That worked perfectly!!! Maybe you could answer one more question though, what if you want to call like multiple variables from other subs, like 10 of them or something? Would you basically just write the code completely differently so you AREN'T having to call them from another sub? Like just put them into the same sub or something? or is that where you would declare them before any subs in the module?

Comment: That is personal preference, I like to break up my subs into smaller ones, especially if I am doing the same mechanics repeatedly.  An I tend to stay away from global variables and pass what is needed, even if it is ten at the time of call, But that is an opinion and you will get many on this site. @Robillard

Comment: @Robillard also when the question is 15 minutes old you will be able to mark this question as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Please do so as it will remove it from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Awesome thanks! So if you were calling 10 variables from other subs, you would write it like

    Sub whatever(thing1, thing2, thing3, thing10)

using 10 variables?

Comment: @Robillard basically, but make sure you declare the type: `Whatever(Thing1 as string, Thing2 as rng,....)`

Comment: Like @ScottCraner said, this is personal preference but much like scott, I try to stay away from global variables. If I have to pass that many, I would use an Array or a collection. That gives me the flexibility to add remove items from it as well at a later date. Although they are not binding so have to be careful how you use them

Comment: @Zac yeah I like using the smaller subs and calling them using one to group them together. I can keep things separated easier. I don't have to pass that many but I was just wondering if I ever come across that. I don't do much coding but I am trying to do more. I am not even really sure how to use arrays or a collection so hopefully I can avoid that until I learn more haha. I have seen some things about how to use an array but I just didn't get it. I would have to spend more time learning how to use them I was trying to figure out other problems.

Comment: @ScottCraner ah yeah I forgot that part. Awesome thank you very much for your help. That was the last little bit for my Macros in my first Excel report. It all works great now! Well except for looping the Inputbox but that isn't that important right now.

Answer (score 0):

Either make your procedures (Sub) accept a parameter for handing over the worksheet Name, i.e.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim name As String

    name = InputBox("Please enter worksheet name")

    'call your other procedures
    Change_Header_Color name

End Sub

Sub Change_Header_Color(ByVal name As String)

    'do some stuff here

    'use the input from the parameter in some way
    Worksheets("foo").Range("A1").Value = name

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can define a global variable and use if across the different Subs.

```
Private name As String

Sub Main()

    name = InputBox("Please enter worksheet name")

    'call your other procedures
    Change_Header_Color

End Sub

Sub Change_Header_Color()

    'do some stuff here

    'use the input from the parameter in some way
    Worksheets("foo").Range("A1").Value = name

End Sub
```

Comment: The other answer worked really well but I appreciate your help as well and will keep it in mind.

Comment: The option using parameter is to be preferred. Actually, the same as my first option.